# In Highcharts, any way we can get the plotWidth and plotHeight before rendering the chart?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, data-visualization

I know that we may find the `plotWidth` and `plotHight` after chart rendering. After rendering a chart:

```
var someChart = $("someContainer").Highcharts(someChartOptions);
```

We may find `someChart.plotWidth` and `someChart.plotHeight`.

But seems they are only calculated after the chart is rendered. Are there any way we can find out or predict the plotting area width and height before rendering.

Comment: Keep the chart invisible get the plotWidth & plotHeight then display it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`plotWidth` and `plotHeight` values are calculated dynamically when rendering. If you set [`margin`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.margin), then those calculations are not done and set values are used instead. Knowing size of a chart and margins you can predict plotWidth and plotHeight before creating the chart.

For chart with set `margin` as `[50, 20, 80, 70]` and chart's container size being 600px x 400px you will get (in pixels):

- `plotHeight` = 270 = 400 - (50 + 80)
- `plotWidth` = 510 = 600 - (20 + 70)

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/prc4o789/

Comment: But with legend enabled, the container size becomes unpredictable again, is there any waywe can acquire the legend width or height?

Comment: @Feedfedfat Legend doesn't force size change - if there is not enough room for the legend, then it will overlap the chart - http://jsfiddle.net/prc4o789/1/. So you should increase bottom margin - http://jsfiddle.net/prc4o789/2/

Comment: Thanks a lot, this seems to be a valid answer.